# How to update table location in Databricks on Azure from wasb to abfss

Tags: azure-databricks, delta-lake

I created a table including location such as:

```
wasb://<container>@<storageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/foldername
```

We have updated access to storage accounts to use `abfss`

I am trying to execute the following command:

```
alter table mydatabase.mytable    
set location ' abfss://<container>@<storageaccount>.dfs.core.windows.net/foldername
```

I am getting the error:

```
Failure to initialize configuration for storage account <storageaccount>.dfs.core.windows.net: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.keyInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
```

On the cluster I have changed:

```
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.<storageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net {{secrets/<proyect>/<storageaccount>}}
```

to this:

```
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.<storageaccount>.dfs.core.windows.net {{secrets/<proyect>/<storageaccount>}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are facing is regarding to storage account key configuration.
You set the key as below.

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<adls_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net","adls_account_key")
```

After setting that. Try altering the table.

But you can also follow bellow approach also using `dbutils`.

Below is the data i created.

```
CREATE  TABLE  user
(
id  INT,
name STRING,
age INT
)
USING  DELTA
LOCATION  'wasbs://container@<storage_acc_name>.blob.core.windows.net/user_data/';
```

[image]

Next, moving all files to adls account.

```
dbutils.fs.mv("wasbs://<container>@<storage_acc_name>.blob.core.windows.net/user_data/","abfss://container@<adls_storage_acc_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/user_data/",recurse=True)
```

Know, you can see records moved to adls account.

```
select  *  from  delta.`abfss://data@jadls2.dfs.core.windows.net/user_data/`;
```

[image]

Comment: In my case the directory has not change. The only change is the access. Would the dbutils move actually "move" data? If so I can't do this because it is a really large operation.

Comment: when you do alter on adls storage, destination location should be of delta format else you will get error as the location is not of delta format. Having you tried to do alter command after setting the key?

Comment: yes. dbutils moves all files to destination.

Comment: It is delta format. I set the key on the spark.config to run when cluster is created. I have tried to do alter statement after and is not working

Comment: ok. what is the error you getting?  after setting the key and running alter command.

Comment: The one I included. I am talking to a colleague and there might be an issue with firewall configuration.